# Ruby on Rails order by id (and version?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

While trying to search with id sorting (and paginating) im getting from the log:

```
SELECT `audits`.* FROM `audits` ORDER BY version, id DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I am currently using this code:

```
@records = Audit.order("id DESC").page(page).per(50)
```

The problem is that the list retrieved is not correctly sorted by id descending.

BTW i am using audited-activerecord gem for audits, does this matter?

Comment: It appears that this gem internally writes a default_scope ordering by version in your models. Try searching in the gem documentation if you can disable this default_scope for some models.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm guessing that your gem is setting a default scope on the Audit model that orders by version, so at the moment it is ordering in ascending order by the version column, and, only if two records are the same, is it ordering by id in descending order.

To fix this, you can prepend `unscoped` to your chain:

```
Audit.unscoped.order("id DESC").page(page).per(50)
```

Answer (score 8):

try:

```
@records = Audit.except('order').order("id DESC").page(page).per(50)
```

the `except('order')` should remove any order relations added to the query

Comment: Interesting, never knew about `except` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Audit.descending.page(page).per(50)
```

[reference from the source](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/master/lib/audited/audit.rb)

Comment: add some description to it.